# lodash for "select by object path"?

Tags: javascript, lodash

Let's say I have this object (or an array of these objects):

```
var person = {
    birth: {
        place: {
            country: 'USA'
        }
    }
};
```

I thought there was a lodash function where I could pass in `'birth.place.country'` and get back the value `USA`.

Is there such a function in lodasdh 3.x, or am I Imagining this?

Comment: This one is a hard one to search for thanks for asking :)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You could use the [`_.get`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get) function:

```
_.get(person, 'birth.place.country', 'optionalDefaultValue');
```

lodash also provides a function called `_.result` that can also call functions.

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I get lost in the docs with so many similar-seeming functions.

Answer (score 5):

Note: for an array of these objects

`_.map(people, 'birth.place.country')`

provides the same functionality as undefined's answer

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would do it in 2023:

```js
const get = (obj, path) => path.reduce((acc, p) => acc?.[p], obj);

get({ a: { b: { c: 1 } } }, ['a', 'b', 'c']); // 1
get({ a: { b: { c: 1 } } }, 'a.b.c'.split('.')); // 1
get({ a: { x: { c: 1 } } }, ['a', 'b', 'c']); // undefined
get({ a: { b: { c: null } } }, ['a', 'b', 'c']); // null
```

With default:

```js
const get = (obj, path, def) => path.reduce((acc, p) => acc?.[p], obj) ?? def;

get({ a: { b: { c: 1 } } }, ['a', 'b', 'c'], 9); // 1
get({ a: { x: { c: 1 } } }, ['a', 'b', 'c'], 9); // 9
get({ a: { b: { c: null } } }, ['a', 'b', 'c'], 9); // 9
```

The difference with Lodash is that `??` checks if a left-hand side operand is null or undefined, while Lodash provides undefined-only check. Could be fixed by using `typeof` or `=== void 0` condition.