# How to dynamically (by path) update a React state property

Tags: javascript, object

I'm trying to change a property value in my react state by using a path:

```
handleChange = (e, path) => {
    e.persist();

    let newState = this.state || {};
    (newState[path] || {})[e.target.name] = e.target.value;
    this.setState(newState);
}
```

The problem is, newState[path] is undefined while typing the path is just working fine.

```
console.log(path); //form.section[0]
console.log(newState[path]); //undefined
console.log(newState.form.section[0]); { type: "person", gender: "female", ... }
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Try console.log(newState[\`${path}\`])

Comment: @MuhammadZeeshan Still undefined

Answer (score 2):

`newState` does not have a property named "form.section[0]", which is what you're attempting to access when you write `newState[path]`. `newState` does have a property named "form", which is an object with a property named "section" (which is an array). that's why writing `newState.form.section[0]` gives you the result you want.

you should probably use `lodash.get` as mentioned here: [lodash for "select by object path"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35207117/lodash-for-select-by-object-path)

Answer (score 0):

`newState[path]` is evaluated to `newState[form.section[0]]`, which depends on value of `form.section[0]`, for example if `form.section[0] === 'john'` then you get `newState.john` which is undefined.

It's different than `newState.form.section[0]` which is actually `newState['form']['section']['0']`. This is more a pure JS question rather than a React one.

Without a bit more context about the rest of your component, my advice would be to simplify the `path` that is given to your `handleChange` handler. Just use a unique field id instead of a composite path. Then the code could be something like:

```
handleChange = (e, fieldId) => {

  //...

  this.setState({
    [fieldId]: e.target.value
  })
}
```